# if statement in python

Tags: python

I can not figure out why my code is not working,

```
key_one= raw_input("Enter key (0 <= key <= 127): ")

if key_one in range(128):
    bin_key_one=bin(key_one)[2:]
    print bin_key_one               
else:
    print "You have to enter key (0 <= key <= 127)"
```

when i enter a number between 0 and 127, it keeps on going to the else!
can some one tell me why?

Comment: A side note: in your `if` statement, `0 <= int(key_one) < 128` will be **way** more efficient than `int(key_one) in range(128)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input` will return a string, so your `if` comparison fails (you're comparing an int with a string).  Try casting:

```
key_one = int(raw_input('enter key: '))
```

Answer (score 3):

`raw_input` returns a string and `"93"` is NOT in `range(128)`.

To make sure you compare apples to apples, cast `key_one` to `int`:

```
key = int(raw_input("Enter key (0 <= key <= 127): "))
if key in range(128)
   # if condition
else
   # else condition
```

**EDIT**: Python documentation is awesome, so if you have questions, it's a great idea to train by reading the docs first.

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.
>   - http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input

Comment: No problem. Glad you figured it out.